# SQL Server stored procedure does not update database via linq

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, t-sql

I have this stored procedure in my SQL Server database:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertOrUpdateUserWorkingHours]
    @Id INT,
    @DateTimeStart DATETIME,
    @DateTimeEnd DATETIME,
    @WorkTime INT,
    @LatStart DECIMAL (9,6),
    @LongStart DECIMAL (9,6),
    @LatEnd DECIMAL (9,6),
    @LongEnd DECIMAL (9,6),
    @CompanyId INT,
    @UserId INT,
    @PageId INT
AS 
BEGIN
    IF (@Id = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.UserWorkingHours ([DateTimeStart], [LatStart], [LongStart],
                                          [DateTimeEnd], [LatEnd], [LongEnd],
                                          [WorkTime], [UserId], [CompanyId],
                                          [IsDeleted], [CreatedOn], [CreatedBy])
        VALUES (@DateTimeStart, @LatStart, @LatEnd, 
                @DateTimeEnd, @LatEnd, @LongEnd,
                @WorkTime, @UserId, @CompanyId,
                0, GETDATE(), @UserId)

        SELECT @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.UserWorkingHours 
        SET [DateTimeStart] = @DateTimeStart,
            [DateTimeEnd] = @DateTimeEnd,
            [LatStart] = @LatStart,
            [LongStart] = @LongStart,
            [LatEnd] = @LatEnd,
            [LongEnd] = @LongEnd,
            [WorkTime] = @WorkTime,
            [UpdatedOn] = GETDATE(),
            [CreatedBy] = @UserId
        WHERE [id] = @Id
    END

    SELECT ISNULL(@Id, 0) AS InsertedId;
END
```

I am calling this procedure from my MVC application with this method:

```
 using (this.objDataContext = new UserWorkingHoursDataContext(serverConnection))
{
    var result = this.objDataContext.InsertOrUpdateUserWorkingHours(objSave.Id,
        objSave.DateTimeStart,
        objSave.DateTimeEnd,
        (int)objSave.WorkTime.TotalMinutes,
        (decimal)objSave.LatStart,
        (decimal)objSave.LongStart,
        (decimal)objSave.LatEnd,
        (decimal)objSave.LongEnd,
        objSave.CompanyId,
        objSave.UserId,
        PageMaster.UserWorkingHours).FirstOrDefault();

    if (result != null)
    {
        return result.InsertedId;
    }
}
```

Every time I use this procedure, I am getting the inserted Id from database, but no rows are inserted into the table. No exceptions are thrown and everything looks fine. Maybe I am missing something obvious?

Comment: If no rows are being inserted, that implies that you're updating one instead; as the above handles both, and returns the value of `@ID` regardless of if the process is an `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.

Comment: Also, if `@ID` may not be known (as it's a new row) why is it a **compulsory** parameter?

Comment: @Larnu thank you for your time, but every time I send data with Id = 0 I am getting new inserted Id as result but no new row is added to table. Id is compulsory because of the object model I am handling inside my mvc appliacation.

Comment: Is there a trigger on the table? The fact that you are getting a (I assume) non-zero value for `@Id` implies *something* else is going on.

Comment: There is no trigger on the table. When I execute stored procedure in MSSM studio with same parameters the rows are getting inserted. I suppose the problem is related with linq to sql dbml.

Comment: Are you calling the stored procedure inside `using (var trans = new TransactionScope())` and forgetting to call `trans.Complete()`?

Comment: Brilliant! How stupid of me. You saved my day.